# How old is Bruce Wayne during Gotham?

Tags: dc, batman, super-hero, gotham

How old Bruce Wayne in each season of Gotham? We know he was 12 when his parents died but what about the rest of the seasons?

Comment: I’ve narrowed it down to somewhere between a bit older than 12, and somewhat older than 12.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/how-old-is-bruce-in-gotham-season-4/

Answer (score 4):

While not said explicitly, he is 12 in the pilot, and by season 4, we see a birthday cake for him in S4E18 which has either 17 or 18 candles on it (I had trouble seeing them clearly) which we can assume means he is 17/18 by the end of season 4.

Filling the gaps this is my rough guess:

Pilot- 12

S1- 13

S2- 14

S3- 15/16

S4- 17/18

S5- 18

And of course the final episode of season 5 there is a 10 year time skip, making him around 28 years old by the very end.

Here is an image from a reddit post in which they counted out the candles on the cake from Bruce’s S4 birthday.

[image: https://i.redd.it/vxa2oizfmtr01.jpg]

https://www.reddit.com/r/Gotham/comments/8c5xhi/s4e18_bruces_birthday_has_18_candles_confirmed_age/

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul D. Waite said, he is 12 in the pilot episode, approaching 13 by the end of S1.

Now, i once read a threat in reddit (posted below) that i could not agree more with, where someone said:

> Time is a little nebulous on the show

Which makes every answer come with a degree of uncertainty, as it is not confirmed nor denied.

I tend to think that they try and keep it as close to David Mazouz's age while filming, so my guess would be that he is 14/15 in S2, 16 in S4 and in S5 it can be narrowed down to 17 approacing 18, as he is old enough to legally drive (Young bruce is following the law :P), yet not old enough to live independently.

Resources:

> https://screenrant.com/how-old-is-bruce-in-gotham-season-4/
> https://www.quora.com/How-old-is-Bruce-Wayne-in-Gotham-TV-show
> https://www.reddit.com/r/Gotham/comments/e3lsgt/how_old_is_bruce_wayne_in_season_4/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please quote the specific pieces of evidence, and if possible please try to dig back to the original sources instead of someone else's analyses.